# radio buttons validation and highlighting when unchecked

Tags: jquery

I have a function to validate radio buttons:

```
$scope.validateForm = function() {
     var radios = document.getElementsByName( "variant" );
     var formValid = false;

     var i = 0;
     while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
         if (radios[ i ].checked) formValid = true;
         i++;
     }

     if (!formValid)
        document.getElementById('variantA').style.color="red";
        document.getElementById('variantB').style.color="red";
        document.getElementById('variantD').style.color="red";

     return formValid;
}
```

This function changes the color of unchecked radios' spans to red.
I'd like to change the spans' color back, when one of the radios is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unset the color by setting it to `null`.

```
$scope.validateForm = function() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName( "variant" );
  var formValid = false;

  var i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[ i ].checked) formValid = true;
      i++;
  }

  document.getElementById('variantA').style.color = formValid  ? null : "red";
  document.getElementById('variantB').style.color = formValid  ? null : "red";
  document.getElementById('variantD').style.color = formValid  ? null : "red";

  return formValid;
}
```